# How to get a standard Salesforce report chart to appear in a Digital Experience (AKA a Community)?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, reporting, lightning-community

In the the Builder, I can add the platform's standard "Report Chart" Lightning Web Component (LWC) and select a pre-existing report and the charts display fine. There I am running as a "Salesforce" licensed "System Administrator" user.

But when a login to the Experience Site as a "Customer Community Plus Login" licensed user, the charts are presented as blank screen. I have:

- Checked that this license type supports reports according to the checked "Reports Create and Manage" checkbox in the [Communities User Licenses](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5) page
- I have the [Set Up Report Management for External Users—Create and Edit Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_reporting_external_users_report_mgmt.htm&type=5) steps done
- I have the "Default External Access" set to "Public Read/Write" for all the objects in the "Sharing Settings" page
- I have read access set on all the objects and fields via permission sets
- The problem is not listed in [Common issues and errors related to viewing reports in Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000351337&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1)

What have I missed?

Comment: have you given the profile they use the ability to [run reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_enable_report_options.htm&type=5)?

Comment: Yes. Think I've found the problem - report folder sharing. Will post as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Having eliminated the items I listed above, it looks like I had missed sharing the report folder appropriately.

The simplest was seems to be to share that folder via a "Partner Role":

[image: share report folder screen shot]

I can now see the reports via a "Customer Community Plus Login" user that has that "Acme Customer User" role.

I need to investigate how that role gets created/assigned; "Acme" is the name of the Account that the login's Contact is a child of.

The need to use **Share** is listed in [Set Up Report Management for External Users—Create and Edit Reports](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_reporting_external_users_report_mgmt.htm&type=5); it just didn't register when I read the page a couple of days ago.

Comment: in terms of the roles, that gets auto-created based on the contact's account (as you noted). You can [change the number of customer roles per account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_default_roles.htm&type=5) for up to 3 different roles (ex. Executive, Manager, User) but the default is one.

Comment: Thanks Kris and helpful link.